# How to use local or session storages in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to set item to session storage when i get response from my ssr app, but it shows error that session storage is not defined, because in server side there is no storages like that, there is only cookie but I don't need that.

So my question is how can I set items to sessionsStorage from getInitialProps in NextJS

Comment: https://dev.to/devlargs/nextjs-hook-for-accessing-local-or-session-storage-variables-3n0 looks really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set items to `sessionsStorage` when calling `getInitialProps`, because `getInitialProps` runs on the server side.

When calling a method of the `window` object, you can first determine whether the `window` object is undefined.

If you use hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window) { 
      // set props data to session storage or local storage  
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: window object is always defined in useEffect

Answer (score 8):

I've created a custom hook for this to avoid SSR errors. The code inside the `useEffect` hook will be executed on client side only so you do not need to check `window`.

hooks/useSessionStorage.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useSessionStorage = (name) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(sessionStorage.getItem(name))
  }, [])

  return value
}

export default useSessionStorage
```

SomeComponent.js

```
import useSessionStorage from '../hooks/useSessionStorage'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const zipCode = useSessionStorage('zipCode')

  return (
    <input value={zipCode} />
  )
}
```

Comment: How would this set the value on the client side?

Answer (score 3):

`getInitialProps` would be executed in client-side or in server-side. So, you need to prevent access `sessionStorage` in server-side.

```
Page.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.sessionStorage.set('item', 'itemValue')
  }
}
```